# How do I use VHDL generic parameters when I place a sheet symbol in Altium?

Tags: vhdl, altium

I'm using Altium Designer Winter 09 to synthesise a design for an FPGA. This includes a VHDL-defined entity `MyShifter` that includes `generic` parameters so I can have it be reuseable:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.Std_Logic_1164.all;

entity MyShifter is

generic
(
       data_width : positive;
       pad_width : positive
);

port
(
    -- ...other ports...
    DataIn        : in std_logic_vector(data_width-1 downto 0)
);

-- architecture follows...
```

With any other VHDL entity I could just right click on a schematic and use `Place » Sheet Symbol`, and then synchronise the sheet entries with the ports defined in VHDL. Altium will, later on, automatically generate the higher-level VHDL that maps ports to other ports and I don't have to worry about it.

When I try this with my entity-with-generics, I end up with sheet entry labelled `DataIn[-1..0]`. This is unsurprising, since I haven't "told" Altium what `data_width` actually is.

My question is: how do I tell Altium what the generic parameters `data_width` and `pad_width` are for a particular instance of `MyShifter`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure a good solution exists.  You could add a second VHDL file that instantiates your first VHDL file's entity with the appropriate generic map.  Then you could just place that second-level VHDL file onto the schematic.

Not ideal, but it maintains reusability, as you can just make new second-level files for every different size you want, and you only have to change the first-level file to affect all instantiations.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding it as a parameter to the sheet symbol?

Double-click on the sheet symbol, Go to the parameters tab, and add a parameter `data_width`. I would guess you want it of type `INTEGER`.

I'm kinda guessing here. I don't really use Altium with logic synthesis.

[image: Yes, my window theme is pink. You got a problem with that?]

You may have to correct the sheet-entry labels manually after you add a parameter (or maybe just recompile the project).

---

Alternatively:

I know you can define project variables, but I don't know if they are presented to the VHDL synthesis system. If `data_width` is used in multiple places (and is the same everywhere), it may be worth trying.

Project >> Project Options >> "Parameters" tab.
It does not have the data-type options of the sheet-symbol, as described below, so it's possible that the VHDL synthesis system does not see project parameters.

Comment: Neither adding it as a parameter nor as a project parameter worked. Too bad :/

Comment: @detly - Well, then I'm out of ideas.

Comment: <Dr. Claw voice>AltiUUUUUUUUUUM!</voice>

Comment: Maybe take a look at the [Altium VHDL Synthesis Reference](http://wiki.altium.com/display/ADOH/VHDL+Synthesis+Reference). Some of the error messages it describes deal with improperly declared constants. It may point you in a promising direction. (Ctrl+f and type "constant")

Comment: You may have to tie a minimal VHDL file into the schematic hierarchy at the highest-level, and define all your constants there. Then they *should* propagate everywhere (I think. I don't really know VHDL).

Comment: I don't think that would allow me to define different `data_width`s, etc, for different instances though.

Answer (score 0):

1- If you add parameters to the VHDL symbol as suggested above:
[image]

this will add the following code the the VHDL file:
[image]

2- The easiest way to get the results that you requested, is just to add a single line at the beginning of the vhdl file:

[image]

to verify that this works, you can quickly synchronize the symbol with the vhdl sheet